# Reading ptp master offset from C code (using /dev/ptp0)

Tags: linux, ptp

I have ptp4l and phc2sys running on my embedded device. What I need is to somehow read ptp master offset from another kernel module. Can I do it from /dev/ptp0 and how? I thoroughly study testptp.c but didn't find there a solution for reading master offset value....

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately so far I didn't...